# Any idea how to make Google Chrome render a PDF when it's URL contains non-utf8 and non-ascii (but url-encoded) chars?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, encoding

Google Chrome seems to have Problems in rendering a PDF file, if the URL to that file contains non-ascii and non-utf8 url-encoded chars.

This is reproducible in a very simple way:

1. Take any http-url to a PDF file.
2. Just add the url-parameter string '?a=%F6' to the given url ('%F6' is the url-encoded value of the german umlaut 'ö' in win-1252 codepage)

Chrome will not render the PDF file.

If you add an utf8 string that is url-endcoded it'll work: e.g: '?a=%C3%B6'

This is confirmed with newest Google Chrome and Chromium (45.0) versions on Windows and Linux.

I read this [blog](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding), but didn't find a hint that non-utf8 encodings wouldn't work.

If i disable the 'PDF viewer Plugin' (in about:plugins) then the PDF is getting downloaded at least.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: What does "not render" mean? What do you get instead? I dare say the most likely explanation is that your web server simply does not return the PDF if you use the wrong URL, no?!

Comment: 'Not render' means the page simple stay blank. I made sure the PDF file is transfered to the browser by checking in the developer tools and by monitoring this by Fiddler.

Comment: As i alerady mentoined this is reproducable with any PDF file, doesn't have to be on my webserver.

Comment: Reading the blog link, there is a note that says "The latest version of the URI standard defines that new URI schemes use UTF-8"

Comment: Scanning through the RFC3986 reveals more details "When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual data consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [UCS], the data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8 character encoding [STD63]; then only those octets that do not correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent-encoded."

Comment: Thanks for that hint, about RFC3986. I thought this refers to 'new' scheme only. As http and https isn't such a 'new' scheme i think this doesn't match here, does it?